# ROS Hydro on beaglebone black rev c

Tags: navigation, beaglebone, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

About six months ago I was able to use Ubuntu 12.04 and sudo-apt-get to install ros-hydro-navigation without any dependency errors. Trying to  do this a second BBB has not been as easy ros-base  installed easily, but navigation now has   many dependency problems.  I suspect these are related to libboost version problems (my version is 1.46), but I am not sure:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 ros-hydro-navigation : Depends: ros-hydro-amcl but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-base-local-planner but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-carrot-planner but it is not going tobe installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-clear-costmap-recovery but it is not  going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-costmap-2d but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-dwa-local-planner but it is not going  to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-fake-localization but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-map-server but it is not going to be  installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-move-base but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-move-slow-and-clear but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-nav-core but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-navfn but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-robot-pose-ekf but it is not going to  be installed
                    Depends: ros-hydro-rotate-recovery but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

the following did install:

- ros-hydro-ros-base
- python-rosdep
- ros-hydro-sensor-msgs
- ros-hydro-image-transport
- ros-hydro-uvc-camera
- ros-hydro-dynamic-reconfigure
- ros-hydro-common-msgs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191602/ros-hydro-on-beaglebone-black-rev-c/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2014-08-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2014-09-01**:
Upgrading libboost from 1.46 to 1.48 did not work, in fact it removed all of the ros packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

sudo aptitude install ros-hydro-navigation

Seemed to work -  issue was with c libraries.  So it might be when I installed build-essentials, it was with the wrong flavor.

Darn, It took me two days to figure out this one. It is helps to be stubborn.

---

Originally posted by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) with karma: 147 on 2014-09-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0